# HDMI issue with Macbook pro 8,1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, hdmi, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook pro (MBP) 8,1  OSX version 10.7.5, and I'm am running Ubuntu 14.04

I have been trying to connect my MBP to my TV with my HDMI cable but it seems like Ubuntu 
does not detect anything and I cannot see any change whether it is on the TV or laptop.

I know it must have to do with drivers but I'm lost I don't know what software/drivers to install to make it work.

Comment: I have the same issue in 14.10, any update?

Comment: NEvermind, it worked, was my fault not plugin the cable correctly. It works without any configuration in Ubuntu 14.10, installed on a Mac 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to Ubuntu 14.10.

I have the same model of Mac, and audio/video works as expected, if you want to duplicate the content of your monitor in your TV, in the "Screens" Control Panel of Ubuntu, check the "Mirror screens" option.